# How to have VSCode immediately replace a word

Tags: visual-studio-code

For... some-odd years now, I have repeatedly mispelled the word "local".  The most common mistake for me is "lcoal".

Is there a trick, a tip, a plugin for VSCode that would see a specific word I give it (lcoal) and *immediately* replace with "local"?  I use this as a scope (local.x) constantly in my language of choice.

I don't want a "bad underline", or syntax throw up, or even an alert.  I just want VSCode to *replace it immediately*.  I don't want to have to search and replace.  And this language doesn't have any kind of pre-processor before running.

Is there anything like that?  My Googling and searching extensions didn't turn up anything useful.

(I think I was able to do this in Sublime before I ever switched to VSCode.) And yes, I should just learn to spell it correctly.  I get that. And 99% of the time I do, but that 1% is a killer for me.

Comment: Try autohotkey...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is the [HyperSnips](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips) extension.  It is fairly easy to set up.  Remember to `HyperSnips: Reload Snippets` if you make any changes.

You would make a "snippet" like this, in your `<language>.hsnips` file:

```
snippet `(lcoal)` "replace lcoal with local." A
``rv='local\.'``
endsnippet
```

The `A` at the end makes it "automatic" - you could add the `.` to snippet prefix if you wish - so that it is not triggered until you type the `.`:

```
snippet `(lcoal\.)` "replace lcoal. with local." A
``rv='local\.'``
endsnippet
```

[image: HyperSNips mispelling demo]

This:

```
snippet `(lc)` "replace lc with local." A
``rv='local\.'``
endsnippet
```

automatically replaces `lc` => `local.`

Comment: THIS is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you SO much.  Worked exactly as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Auto correct Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sygene.auto-correct).

[image: Extension inside VSCode]

I tried it out and it works for your usecase. The only pain is that you have to setup the words manually in your `settings.json` file if they are not in the `useLargeList` that is deactivated per default.

Go to:

File/Code -> Preferences -> Settings -> User:Extensions:Auto Correct Configuration -> `Edit in settings.json`

[image: User:Extension:Auto Correct Configuration]

Paste the following configuration or add the `"auto-correct.dictionary"` entry, save and restart

```json
{
    "auto-correct.dictionary": [
        {
            "languages": [
                "*"
            ],
            "words": {
                "lcoal": "local"
            },
            "useLargeList": true
        },
    ]
}
```

[image: sample settings.json]

Now `lcoal` will be automatically changed to `local`

[image: lcoal gets automatically transformed to local gif animation]

Comment: I will check this, thanks @Leonhard Bauer.  This is exactly what I wanted.  Manually entering the words in a dictionary is perfectly fine.  Thanks for the contribution!

Comment: I wasn't able to get it running as expected.  But it LOOKS like the right answer.  I must not be configuring correctly.  I add the "auto-correct..." config section into the JSON, but...doesn't seem to be kicking in.

Comment: I added screenshots to show how it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to search icon then press `cont + shift + h` then enter search term and replace term.. now you can easily find all occurrence of your word and replace them easily

Comment: No, this is the opposite of "immediate".  Sitting at a machine for 35+ years, I know about search and replace.